# cider keg carbonation problem

Tags: carbonation, kegging, force-carbonation

I have applied a method seen on youtube where the keg was laid down and rocked by foot rolling it back and forth for about 5 minutes. Trouble is I did not get much bubbles after about letting it settle for 1.5 hours. I used [this graph](https://www.kegoutlet.com/keg-carbonation-chart.html)

- carb PSI was 26 for 60F temperature currently in my cellar
- after the rocking lowered the PSI to about 7 for serving and let it settle

What else can I try to get it carbonated ? This is a commercial 50 liter keg.

Answer (score 1):

I carbonate all my beers and cider, first get your cider cold, really cold. CO2 will get in solution more quickly when your target is cold.  Your 60F temp hindered your process.  I set my frig at 36F for usually 24 hours. If you put a fairly high level 30 psi of CO2 and do the “shake and roll” method, you usually can get your beer/cider carbed pretty quickly.  Here’s an article comparing Burst vs Forced carbonation.  Refer to this, as its kind of waste of time for me to retype it all here.
https://brucrafter.com/what-is-burst-carbonation/

Comment: are there any pressure/time charts for other temperatures ? I won't be able to bring it below 60 F. Thanks

Comment: https://brucrafter.com/keg-carbonation-calculator/

Comment: "It can take days or even weeks to reach the desired level when carbonating at serving pressure." So I still don't know for how long I should wait before lowering the pressure.

Comment: Yes it can and does, SP is usually 6 psi or lower.  It will take several weeks at that psi. How soon are you planning or needing to serve this cider, that will set the parameters for your carbing psi.  I carb my cold cider around 14 psi and it takes all of 2 weeks and a bit to get where I want it, no shaking involved.   The fact that you can’t get it cold is going to add a fair amount of time.

Comment: In my experience cider is not easy to carb up.  It has been almost like carbing up a soda.  Need it cold, need it higher psi, and takes longer.  Tony has good advice.